# Java Map with multiple tiers

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm trying to get the data below into some form of Java structure. 
*The data represents a tennis tournament where Joe beat Ken 6-3, 6-4 and Sally beat Lucy 6-4, 2-6, 6-1*.
As far as I could understand I should be able to use a normal map, something like this `Map1<Key1, Map2<Key2, Map3<Key3, Value>>>`
What throws me off is that I will not go down to the last tier (**GameResult**) every time. Look at the variables for **FixtureResult** and **MatchResult** as an exmaple. Also, every **MatchResult** will have multiple **GameResult** sets, so how do I give those **GameResult** objects unique keys from a **MatchResult** (parent) perspective?

```
<FixtureResult>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <FixtureId>1</FixtureId>
    <DateSubmitted>07-01-2017</DateSubmitted>

    <MatchResult>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <WinnerName>Joe</WinnerName>
        <LoserName>Ken</LoserName>  

        <GameResult>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <WinnerPoints>6</WinnerPoints>
            <LoserPoints>3</LoserPoints>    
            <Ordinal>1</Ordinal>
        </GameResult>

        <GameResult>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <WinnerPoints>6</WinnerPoints>
            <LoserPoints>4</LoserPoints>    
            <Ordinal>2</Ordinal>
        </GameResult>

    </MatchResult>

    <MatchResult>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <WinnerName>Sally</WinnerName>
        <LoserName>Lucy</LoserName> 

        <GameResult>
            <Id>3</Id>
            <WinnerPoints>6</WinnerPoints>
            <LoserPoints>4</LoserPoints>    
            <Ordinal>1</Ordinal>
        </GameResult>

        <GameResult>
            <Id>4</Id>
            <WinnerPoints>2</WinnerPoints>
            <LoserPoints>6</LoserPoints>    
            <Ordinal>2</Ordinal>
        </GameResult>

        <GameResult>
            <Id>5</Id>
            <WinnerPoints>6</WinnerPoints>
            <LoserPoints>1</LoserPoints>    
            <Ordinal>3</Ordinal>
        </GameResult>

    </MatchResult>
</FixtureResult>
```

Comment: This fits in more with List than a Map

Comment: Can you post your best attempt in java code?

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't use your defined structure?

```
class FixtureResult {
  Integer id;
  Integer FixtureId;
  Date dateSubmitted;
  List<MatchResult> matchResults
}
class MatchResult {
  Integer id;
  String winnerName;
  String loserName;
  List<GameResult> gameResults
}
class GameResult {
  Integer id;
  Integer winnerPoints;
  Integer loserPoints;
  Integer ordinal;
}
```

Comment: Hi iMysak, I eventually want to send the data to a php GET method. I'm using classes like you described abpve already, but at some stage I will have to send it all across as one parseable string or something

Comment: so you need serialize the data, with http(s) I would recommend you send xml(if you arleady have it) or json . Jackson or Gson.